# How to add LinkedIn Insight tag in nextjs application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web-deployment, linkedin-api

Where to put LinkedIn insight code on nextjs application.

I tried adding script to _app.jsx inside  tag provided by next/script

> This is the script provided from LinkedIn site

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_linkedin_partner_id = "93XXXX";
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
</script><script type="text/javascript">
(function(l) {
if (!l){window.lintrk = function(a,b){window.lintrk.q.push([a,b])};
window.lintrk.q=[]}
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
var b = document.createElement("script");
b.type = "text/javascript";b.async = true;
b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})(window.lintrk);
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=933188&fmt=gif" />
</noscript>
```

> Here is the code I implemented in Script tag:

```
    <Script
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
            type="text/javascript";
            _linkedin_partner_id = "93XXXX";
            window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = 
            window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];                             
           window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
            (function(l) { 
                if (!l){window.lintrk = function(a,b) 
            {window.lintrk.q.push([a,b])};
            window.lintrk.q=[]} var s = 
            document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            var b = document.createElement("script");
            b.type = "text/javascript";
            b.async = true;
            b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})(window.lintrk);
            <noscript>
                <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=3689532&fmt=gif" />
            </noscript>
`
}}
/>
```

Comment: Remove the `type="text/javascript";` line and add the `<noscript>` tag separately.

Comment: in the image that ur partner id is visible. u better edit it out @Atul

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add to the _document.js file in the pages folder
<Html>
    <Head />
    <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
      {/* linkedIn Tag Script */}
      <script>
        {`
        _linkedin_partner_id = "93XXXX";
        window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = 
        window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];                             
       window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
        (function(l) { 
            if (!l){window.lintrk = function(a,b) 
        {window.lintrk.q.push([a,b])};
        window.lintrk.q=[]} var s = 
        document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        var b = document.createElement("script");
        b.type = "text/javascript";
        b.async = true;
        b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})(window.lintrk);
      `}
      </script>
      <noscript>
        <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=933188&fmt=gif" />
      </noscript>
    </body>
  </Html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).